# Convert CSV XY coordinates to different spatial reference system

Tags: coordinates, xy

I have a CSV containing the eircodes of Ireland (over 1 million records) and their coordinates which are in Irish Transverse Mercator (ITM) Easting and Northing. `717387.8  748192.3`

I am trying to match them up to their nearest air quality monitoring station (there are only 38, also in CSV format), but I have just noticed that their Easting and Northing coordinates are in Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM) - `133386.6  177338`

Does anyone know a quick way to convert the air quality monitor coordinates to ITM Easting and Northings?

Comment: How "quick" do you mean? Just adding an offset and multiplying by a scale? Probably not. The `PROJ` library is the standard tool for reprojection, but you need to know the projection's EPSG code or WKT text. Irish Transverse Mercator is https://epsg.io/2157 or similar? And "UTM" isn't precise without a zone number. PROJ has command line tools (can process CSV) and C level library with major language support (Python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a Python script or a GIS application such as QGIS (see at the end of the answer) or ArcGIS Pro. Since you don't specify into which UTM Zone your data should be projected, I assume it is [WGS84 / UTM Zone 29N](https://epsg.io/32629) (`EPSG:32629`).

**Note:** I realized half way through that you want to project the other way around. This answers converts the coordinates from ITM to UTM Zone 29N. Just switch around the projection in the example below.

---

If you are looking for a Python script, you could simply use `geopandas`:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

EPSG_ITM = 2157
EPSG_UTM29N = 32629

# test data downloaded (and modified):
# https://data.gov.ie/dataset/ballycroy-national-park-story-map-data

# load csv file
gdf = gpd.read_file(r"D:\temp\Ballycroy StoryMap Tour Data.csv")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    gdf,
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(
        gdf["ITM X"].astype(np.float32), gdf["ITM Y"].astype(np.float32)
    )
)
gdf.crs = f"epsg:{EPSG_ITM}"

# re-project the data
gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=EPSG_UTM29N)
gdf["UTM X"] = gdf["geometry"].x
gdf["UTM Y"] = gdf["geometry"].y

gdf.to_csv(r"D:\temp\test.csv")
```

---

Here is an example with QGIS. First, you need to add the CSV file as a layer and tell what your geometry columns are. Then, you have to re-project the layer. And finally save the result back to a CSV file (or another file format).

1. Create/Open a QGIS Project
2. Go to menu `Layer`, `Add Layer`, and then `Add Delimited Text Layer...`
3. Select file
4. Expand `Geometry Definition`
5. Select `Point coordinates`, then select the columns for `X field` and `Y field` (which are in my example `ITM X` and `ITM Y`)
6. Change the `Geometry CRS` to `EPSG:2157`

[image]

7. Click `Add`, then `Close`
8. Go to menu `Processing`, then `Toolbox`
9. Search for `Project`, double click `Reproject layer`

[image]

10. Change the `Target CRS` to the desired projection (I assume that is `EPSG:32629`)

[image]

11. Open the attribute table of the newly created layer
12. Use `Ctrl+E` to switch to the edit mode
13. Use `Ctrl+W` to add a new field `UTM X` with field type `Decimal number (real)`
14. Use `CTRL+I` to open the Field Calculator
15. Select `Create a new field` and use `$x` as expression

[image]

16. Repeat 13 to 15 for `UTM Y` and use `$y` as expression
17. Right click on the layer, click `Make Permanent...`
18. Save as a CSV file

[image]

Comment: Fantastic - thank you for giving me both options!